# Cassandra Cluser update lost

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I'm using datastax cassandra 2.0.9 in cluster of 3 nodes with datastax driver 1.0.3 and sync updates (executeAsync)

In my test I perform sequence of updates for list of existing records, which change some values in those records.

The problem I see is that datastax driver responses with success each time, but the fact is that some records leave unchanged. The important fact is that it never happens on one node cluster.

Keyspace RF is 1, read consistency is default - 1

I just wonder, how would you advise to investigate the issue, as initial attempt to do that didn't give much result. Cassandra logs look good.

Could it be the issue with datastax driver? If yes, could you point me to the appropriate bug in bugtracking system?

Please, share your thoughts. Thanks.

Comment: How do you test? You say you use `executeAsync` which returns success when data is in commit log but could be that it is not applied so you might get timing issues since you do all operation as they are synchronous and you use `executeAsync`?

Comment: Thanks, Nenand, for your feedback. What do I perform is the call to Session#execute(Query query), that performs executeAsync((Query)query).getUninterruptibly() and blocks until operation is performed. Regarding timeouts I wonder where I could find them, as cassandra log file looks good?

Comment: We first used `Thread.sleep()` in our tests to be sure we do not have problems with async executions (sort of gave pause to execution until DB is ready) but that is not right approach since you never know how long will it take, so we created our own session implementation for tests which does `execAsync` as regular sync `exec` so we can test it.

Answer (score 0):

The most common cause of this behavior (if not the only one) is that time is out of sync between your cluster nodes. Then if one of your node inserts data using an accurate timestamp, and another node (with time way behind) tries to update the data with an older timestamp, there is no error, but the data is not updated since the "last write wins" approach chooses the first write to be the winner.